# Find out for missing items across 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Basically I have following 4 tables (including two lookup tables)

My intention is Basically first needs to find out what are the matching records
between ModTab and MedTab through link keys (ItemID & TrfCode through Lookup1) and then 
missing OptCodes in MedTab which are in ModTab and viceversa.

Can I do this with one go

Key fields are the one with same name.

When linking MedTab & Lookup2 needs to use both StateCode and OptCode

```
ModTab
======
Component
Item ID

MedTab
======
TrfCode
OptCode
StateCode



Lookup1
=======
Item ID
TrfCode

Lookup2
========
Component
StateCode
OptCode
```

How should I do it

Appreciate your guidence

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: usually you need a inner join to retrieve matching records, and outer join to get "un-matching" records.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using a `FULL JOIN`, although I'm pretty hazy on the exact workings of your schema, somehting along the lines of this should work:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(ModTab.ItemID, MedTab.ItemID) AS ItemID,
        COALESCE(ModTab.TrfCode, MedTab.TrfCode) AS TrfCode,
        COALESCE(ModTab.Component, MedTab.Component) AS Component,
        COALESCE(ModTab.StateCode, MedTab.StateCode) AS StateCode,
        COALESCE(ModTab.OptCode, MedTab.OptCode) AS OptCode,
        CASE WHEN ModTab.OptCode IS NULL THEN 'MedTab Only'
            WHEN MedTab.OptCode IS NULL THEN 'ModTab Only'
            ELSE 'Both Tables'
        END AS MatchStatus
FROM    (   SELECT  l1.ItemID,
                    l1.TrfCode,
                    l2.Component,
                    l2.StateCode,
                    l2.OptCode
            FROM    ModTab m
                    INNER JOIN Lookup1 l1
                        ON l1.ItemID = m.ItemID
                    INNER JOIN Lookup2 l2
                        ON l2.Component = m.Component
        ) ModTab
        FULL JOIN
        (   SELECT  l1.ItemID,
                    l1.TrfCode,
                    l2.Component,
                    l2.StateCode,
                    l2.OptCode
            FROM    MedTab m
                    INNER JOIN Lookup1 l1
                        ON l1.TrfCode = m.TrfCode
                    INNER JOIN Lookup2 l2
                        ON l2.StateCode = m.StateCode
                        AND l2.OptCode = m.OptCode
        ) MedTab
            ON ModTab.ItemID = MedTab.ItemID
            AND ModTab.TrfCode = MedTab.TrfCode
            AND ModTab.Component = MedTab.Component
            AND ModTab.StateCode = MedTab.StateCode
            AND ModTab.OptCode = MedTab.OptCode;
```

Some of the joins may need to be amended, but the principle is there, basically full join the data sets, this will return all the records from each, where one is null you know there record is not in that set, where both are not null you know the record is in both.

**EDIT**

MS-Access does not support `FULL JOIN` and has a different JOIN syntax for multiple joins so you will have to use UNION to merge the records, then check where the record source is. Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT  ItemID, 
        TrfCode, 
        Component, 
        StateCode, 
        OptCode,
        IIF(SUM(MedTab)=0,'ModTab',IIF(SUM(ModTab)=0,'MedTab','Both')) AS TabStatus
FROM    (   SELECT  Lookup1.ItemID, 
                    Lookup1.TrfCode, 
                    Lookup2.Component, 
                    Lookup2.StateCode, 
                    Lookup2.OptCode,
                    1 AS MedTab,
                    0 AS ModTab
            FROM    (   MedTab
                        INNER JOIN Lookup1
                            ON Lookup1.TrfCode = MedTab.TrfCode
                    )
                    INNER JOIN Lookup2
                        ON Lookup2.StateCode = MedTab.StateCode
                        AND Lookup2.OptCode = MedTab.OptCode
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Lookup1.ItemID, 
                    Lookup1.TrfCode, 
                    Lookup2.Component, 
                    Lookup2.StateCode, 
                    Lookup2.OptCode,
                    0 AS MedTab,
                    1 AS ModTab
            FROM    (   ModTab 
                        INNER JOIN Lookup2 
                            ON ModTab.Component = Lookup2.Component
                    ) 
                    INNER JOIN Lookup1 
                        ON ModTab.ItemID = Lookup1.ItemID
        ) 
GROUP BY ItemID, TrfCode, Component, StateCode, OptCode;
```

I haven't tested this and it is a while since I did any queries in access so fingers crossed it works first time!

Comment: Hi GarethD Thax for your reply. If I want to run this in MS access database. I guess needs to do some syntax changes. Is there any way to change the syntax straightway (May be a tool)        Cheers   Shabar

Comment: There is no tool that I am aware of, but I've added a way of doing it in access.

Comment: One more small clarification.......                                           In case if I want to do the Lookup2.StateCode = MedTab.StateCode as follows how it is possible

If get Lookup2.StateCode value as "A1" needs to check "T1", "T2" values in MedTab.StateCode

But for other values needs to check one to one 
Is this possible in one go

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: By the sounds of it you could use ON `((Lookup2.StateCode = MedTab.StateCode) OR ((Lookup2.StateCode = 'A1') AND (MedTab.StateCode IN ('T1', 'T2'))))`

Comment: Hi Greth   Thanks for your reply                                   In my scenario lookup tables use for get the correspondence code on the other table. For example Lookup1 use for get the correspondence ModTab.ItemID for MedTab.TrfCode                        Likewise   Lookup2 -->  ModTab.Component - MedTab.OptCode, MeTab.StateCode                                                     So in your I guess linking is bit different.                         Sorry It was my mistake that couldn't mentioned that. How it gonna change if that the scenario                    Cheers   Shabar

Comment: Basically first needs to get the valid Items From ModTab - Lookup1 ---MedTab and then get the missing OptCode and SateCode in MedTab for those Valid Item ID        Hope this is more clrearer     Cheers   Shabar

Comment: I don't fully understand your schema still, are you not able to apply the principle of the answer I have posted and just change the joins to get the desired outcome? If not some sample data and expected output would be very helpful.